# Alignment on Android Wear Watch Face

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am new to android watch face development and facing some problem with alignment of time text! I am displaying time in two format, How can I display it one at top and one at bottom and center aligned as shown in image below? Is there any pattern or layout for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you to figure out the alignment yourself when calling `Canvas.drawText` in your `onDraw` handler. I use code something like this:

```
String msg = "Text to display";
float width = paint.measureText(msg);
canvas.drawText(msg, centerX - width / 2f, top, paint);
```

where `paint`, `top`, and `centerX` were all initialized previously. The first two will depend on your face design, while the third is a `Point` field that can be set in your `onCreate` handler like so:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
display.getSize(displaySize);
centerX = displaySize.x / 2f;
```

Alternately, you could do all of this in XML with a [layout-based watch face](https://sterlingudell.wordpress.com/2015/05/10/layout-based-watch-faces-for-android-wear/), but this may or may not be a good fit for your needs.